# Error reading file in java

Tags: java, file-io, input, javax.imageio

I am trying to read a jpeg image in java and convert it into two dimensional array. Code is as follows

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class JpegToArray {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    URL url = JpegToArray.class.getResource("img/abc.jpg");
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int[][] _img = convert_to_2d_Array(img);
}

private static int[][] convert_to_2d_Array(BufferedImage image) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    int[][] result = new int[height][width];

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {

            result[row][col] = image.getRGB(col, row);
            System.out.println(result[row][col]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

When I run ths in Eclipse following error occurs

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
at JpegToArray.main(JpegToArray.java:11)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you check the url?

Comment: What is the value of 'url' after the first line of main has been executed?  If it is null, then img/abc.jpg is not being found on the class path.

Comment: Looks like the image is not found. can you show your project layout? where is the jpg and teh class located? Try `JpegToArray.class.getResource("/img/abc.jpg")`

Comment: Where does the image abc.jpg reside relative to your project?

Comment: Indeed, something is wrong with the project layout and so the image is not found.

Comment: @Jens I tried ("/img/abc.jpg") but it didn't work.

Comment: @Jens img and src folders are inside PR1 folder.

Comment: Can you try `URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("img/abc.jpg");`

Comment: Is the img  folder part of the classpath? If not they cannot be found by the classloader.

Comment: @SyamS I tried    URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("img/abc.jpg");  It gave me same error.

Comment: Can you share your project folder structure?

Comment: @SyamS 
/PR1
|-- bin   
    -- JpegToArray.class
|-- img
   -- abc.jpg
|-- src    
   -- JpegToArray.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your directory structure is as follows and the img folder is not in classpath.

```
/PR1 
|-- bin
    -- JpegToArray.class
|-- img
    -- abc.jpg
|-- src
    -- JpegToArray.java
```

If so you could get the parent directory of class and the refer the image file like

```
String parentPath = new File(JpegToArray.class.getResource("").getPath()).getParent();
URL url = new File(parentPath + "/img/abc.jpg").toURI().toURL();
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Or directly without url like

```
String parentPath = new File(JpegToArray.class.getResource("").getPath()).getParent();
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(parentPath + "/img/abc.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your folder structure there may be some possibility:

1.You have to include your `img` folder in your class path.

> In eclipse to add right-click on an eclipse project and select
>   **Properties**, select the **Java Build Path** link on the left. Then select
>   the **Source** Tab. You'll see a list of all the java source folders. You
>   can even add your own. By default the {project}/src folder is the
>   classpath folder.

If this already been done than you see your image in your deployment folder. In your case it is `bin` it must be present there in folder `img`, but there is no `img` folder or image file in your bin folder.

2.If you do not want to add `img` in your class path than you should keep this `img` folder inside your `src` folder so that it will by default deployed with `src` folder.

If you choose second one than your URL should be crated as below :

```
URL url = Test.class.getResource("/img/acctmanager.png");
```

Make sure that your `img` folder also get deployed with your main `src` folder. You should find it in bin folder if deployed correctly.

I hope this will help you.